# Connecting to a database using Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open a new connection using macro but statement "Rcrdst.Open" is giving me Run-time error: **"ORA-00911: invalid character"**. Can anybody help me to find the issue?

```
Dim C           As Integer
Dim ambiente    As String
Dim userid      As String
Dim Password    As String
Dim Query       As String
Dim Newsht      As Worksheet
Dim Conn        As ADODB.Connection
Dim Rcrdst      As ADODB.Recordset

Set Newsht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
ambiente = InputBox("Please insert environement in which query has to be run.", "Test")
userid = InputBox("Please insert your USER ID for " & ambiente & " environment.", "Test")
Password = InputBox("Please insert the PASSWORD related to " & userid & " user.", "Test")

If userid <> "" And Password <> "" Then
    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA; Password= " & Password & ";User ID= " & userid & "; Data Source = " & ambiente & ";Persist Security Info=True"
    Conn.Open
    Query = "select seq_prenotazione, cod_rapporto,stato_pren from via.prenotazione where seq_prenotazione in (700016298527, 700016761977);"

    Set Rcrdst = New ADODB.Recordset
    Rcrdst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Rcrdst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    Rcrdst.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic

    Rcrdst.Open Query, conn

    'code to work on data extracted

end if    
Rcrdst.Close
Conn.Close
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error occurs when executing the query and the error code is "ORA..", that looks like the error is thrown by your database. The error description is _Identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than letters and numbers. $#\_ are also allowed after the first character._ I would guess your `userid` and `Password` variables contain Italian unicode characters that the database cannot handle. Also, you shouldn't close your connection while other objects (i.e. `Rcrdst`) depend on it.

Comment: my `userid` and `password` both contains only alphabets and numbers and when I copy paste this exact query in SQL developer it runs perfectly.

Comment: I suggest a closer look at the `Query` variable. Your code might change it differently than if you copy it yourself. Have Excel print out the string or look at it in debug mode.

Comment: Try removing the trailing `;`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - thanks man. It worked. i have wasted lots of hours on this silly issue.

Comment: Annoying hey! Many people have wasted time on this issue!

Comment: @BenDot  - Thanks for explaining me the error code and suggesting to have excel print out the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the trailing `;` from the query.

Sometimes you need it sometimes you don't. Maybe an Oracle expert can explain it.